# navigate back and display the previous page without reloading the previous page variables and designs?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one issue in my program, i have three pages in my program, Main page, first page and second page. I'm able to navigate from the main page to the first page and from the first page to the second page. I have a stack panel in the first page. It consists of children which are dynamically created from the db. This page contains a OnNavigateTo method, for bringing the elements from the main page and displaying it, And i wrote my codings in this method to add dynamically children to the stackpanel. when navigating back from the second page to the first page, the compiler will goes to the OnNavigateTo method and regenerate the children of the stackpanel once again.

My problem is:

i want to show the previously displayed first page with all the data, when  the back button is pressed. I doesn't want the page to regenerate again. I want the static page which i have previously when i go back from the second page to the first page.

How to do it? please help me with some piece of code... Thank You..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the logic in the constructor, because it doesn't get called when navigating back (unless the app has been tombstoned). OnNavigatedTo gets called every time no matter how you navigate to the page.

Read this for more info:

[WP7 Development Tip of the Day: Page Startup: The Constructor](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/10/01/WP7-Development-Tip-of-the-Day-Page-Startup-The-Constructor.aspx)